# How to replace codiegniter ajax call to ratchet socket

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter, websocket, ratchet

How to replace codeigniter ajax call to ratchet socket

```
$.ajax({
    url: base_url + "secure/secure_remove_file",
    type: 'POST', 
    cache: true,
    dataType: 'json', 
    data: { 'name': fileName },
    timeout: 120000,
    error: function() {
        alert('error while loading data');
    },
    success: function(pdata) {
        document.getElementById(id).style.display="none";
    }
});
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30813183/setup-codeigniter-and-rachet-socket

https://github.com/kishor10d/CodeIgniter-Ratchet-Websocket

Comment: thanks shafiq. Is that possible I replace every ajax call to ratchet?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setup Codeigniter and Rachet socket](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30813183/setup-codeigniter-and-rachet-socket)

Comment: thanks Kie. One more question in codeigniter I used $_POST method but i getting undefined id method error.